# how to upload optional documents

Tags: laravel

I need to upload few files optional. here I add code

```
<form action="{{ route('UserConfirmation', app()->getLocale()) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="form-group form-control">{{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="tel" name="ContactNo" value="{{ old('ContactNo') }}" required>
  <input class="form-control"  type="file" name="nic" required><br>
  <input class="form-control"  type="file" name="BillingProof" ><br>
  <input class="form-control"  type="file" name="CashSlip" ><br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" ><br>
</div>
</form>
```

here is two required fields, and others are not require,so I need those save in database as empty, here i add my current controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       //dd($request);
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'ContactNo' =>  ['required', 'string','max:15'],
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) { 
        return redirect()->back() ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
     }

    $nicPath = $request->file('nic')->store('public');
    $billPath = $request->file('BillingProof')->store('public');
    $CashSlipPath = $request->file('CashSlip')->store('public');

    $UC = $request->all();
    $UserCon= new UserConfirm();
    $UserCon->ContactNo = $UC['ContactNo'];
    $UserCon->NIC = str_replace('public/', '', $nicPath );
    $UserCon->BillingProof = str_replace('public/', '', $billPath );
    $UserCon->CashSlip = str_replace('public/', '', $CashSlipPath );
    $UserCon->Status = "none";   
    $UserCon->Remark = "none";  
    $UserCon->save();

    Session::flash('UserConfirm','We recived your Documents and we are working on it');
    return redirect()->route('feedback',app()->getLocale());
    }
```

and also I add nullable attribute to table fields. here i attach image of table
[image]

Comment: So what's the problem ? You can add nic as a required field with file type into your validator and then save those two files only if they were sent to the server

Comment: Call to a member function store() on null __showing error in $billPath = $request->file('BillingProof')->store('public');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the file has been sent at first:

```
$billPath = $request->hasFile('BillingProof') ? $request->file('BillingProof')->store('public') : null;
$CashSlipPath = $request->hasFile('CashSlip') ? $request->file('CashSlip')->store('public') : null;
```

and then save it into your storage.

Comment: its showing error syntax, I think shoud be change isset using,